# Bug: "yesterday" tab in responses page shows both yesterday and today

Tags: bug, status-completed, recent-activity

When I click *today* I get this:

> Showing 2009-06-14 to 2009-06-14 ; current time is 2009-06-14 19:12:14 UTC

When I click *yesterday* I get this:

> Showing 2009-06-13 to 2009-06-14 ; current time is 2009-06-14 19:14:44 UTC

So yesterday shows me June 13th (yesterday) **and** June 14th (today). This doesn't seem right.

(Ported from Uservoice)

Comment: It seems to have been fixed, with SO revision 4938 introduced minutes ago. This "bug" could then be marked as "completed"

Answer (score 3):

I will port here my comment on the UV entry:

True: "yesterday" should be the link allowing me to see what I have done yesterday *compared* to today.

Instead, I have to:

- remember the "today" score,
- go to yesterday
- and *mentally subtract" it from the "yesterday score".

Very painful ;)

Comment: Agreed, and it's different from the "last week" link which behaves as expected.

Comment: Or you could just edit the URL to use the correct date range... :)

Answer (score 1):

The query for yesterday should be:

```
where activitytime >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate())-1,0)
  and activitytime <  dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate())  ,0)
```

(using whatever field is appropriate for activitytime)

Edit: Actually, it's just about the link for 'yesterday'. Currently it goes to:

```
.....?StartDate=2009-08-26&EndDate=2009-08-27
```

When it should be:

```
.....?StartDate=2009-08-26&EndDate=2009-08-26
```

So the simple workaround is just to hack the URL you go to.

Rob

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: That seems to be the case since SO revision 4938. Yesterday now means just yesterday!

Comment: Yes, it seems fixed now!

Answer (score 0):

I thought I found something but the magic related titles search found this item.  But this was first posted in back in June so I'm starting to wonder if this is a feature and not a bug.