# Recent page is little confusing

Tags: discussion, recent-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bug: “yesterday” tab in responses page shows both yesterday and today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1265/bug-yesterday-tab-in-responses-page-shows-both-yesterday-and-today)

Yesterday screen show information from yesterday and today. I think, it should displaying information only from yesterday.

And if I click on envelope I get different information, then from Today screen.

Comment: This has been brought up several times.

Comment: @Ian, where? I haven't seen anything before that I can remember.

Comment: Here it izzzzz http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1265/bug-yesterday-tab-in-responses-page-shows-both-yesterday-and-today

Answer (score 1):

I complete agree, right now the yesterday add the parameters: "StartDate=2009-07-22&EndDate=2009-07-23" which means it shows today's activity as well as yesterday's. I believe it should add parameters such that it becomes: "StartDate=2009-07-22&EndDate=2009-07-22".

Answer (score 0):

Dating is relative on SO sites, doesn't always line up with your calendar day.

Comment: But in recent time displaying in UTC.