# Accepted question not shown in today or yesterday

Tags: bug, status-completed, accepted-answer

Quite a rare occurrence, but someone appears to have accepted [my answer](https://superuser.com/questions/81629/nix-window-manager-that-places-window-list-on-window-title-bar/81639#81639) on the exact second of the switchover to the next day (UTC time). It doesn't appear to be related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1265/bug-yesterday-tab-in-responses-page-shows-both-yesterday-and-today) as it was apparently fixed.

Answer accepted at 23:59:59:

[image]

yesterday's view:

[image]

today's view:

[image]

Don't worry about trying to restore the rep - I'm more curious as to why it happened.

Comment: They probably came to their senses and unaccepted the answer.

Comment: If you looked at the link you'd see it's clearly still accepted.

Comment: It does appear in the graph reputation under your profile reputation tab. Should be clocked under 2010-01-11.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that too, very odd. I just thought the today and yesterday tabs would read from the database in the same manner, and sort the event by time accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This was completed when we completed:

[Midnight comment doesn't belong to either day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38526/midnight-comment-doesnt-belong-to-either-day)