# Midnight comment doesn't belong to either day

Tags: bug, status-completed, timestamps, responses, midnight

There seems to be a short time frame around midnight that does not belong  to either day. [This comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23661/#comment-84684), according to the tooltip, was made at 23:59:59 last night (server time). In my responses, it appears in "this week," but neither in "today" nor in "yesterday."

[image]

Comment: The Master is not a vampire. But your cork board looks delicious.

Comment: That graphic is great! And it adds a whole new dimension to freehand circles.

Comment: I don't even understand what your post is about... but +1 for the cork board.

Comment: What's with the obsession over the cork board? This is a simple -- albeit [for Chacha102] well-documented -- bug report :)

Comment: @koper: No repro. Takes about a second for me.

Comment: So what'd you use for the corkboard?  It's great - even has shadows for the pins

Comment: @bobobobo: all put together by hand in the Gimp

Answer (score 14):

On the next data dump, you'll be able to confirm the timestamp on that comment (it's not included in the most recent dump). The data dump contains the timestamps of posts and comments to millisecond resolution.

**Update**: From the April data dump, here's the comment record in question:

```
<row Id="84684" PostId="23661" Score="1" Text="..." CreationDate="2010-02-05T23:59:59.907" UserId="4228" />
```

Sure enough, the comment was posted less than one second before the midnight rollover.

Here's some comments (up to February) that might cause similar trouble:

```
$ psql sof -c "select id, postid, creationdate from comment"|grep 23:59:59
  172364 |  335820 | 2008-12-02 23:59:59.037
  183993 |  350874 | 2008-12-08 23:59:59.50
  282123 |  463524 | 2009-01-20 23:59:59.073
  520148 |    7794 | 2009-04-01 23:59:59.187
  561158 |  749724 | 2009-04-14 23:59:59.137
  574475 |  758349 | 2009-04-17 23:59:59.50
  631688 |  822589 | 2009-05-04 23:59:59.797
  681025 |  870810 | 2009-05-16 23:59:59.077
  834963 | 1024997 | 2009-06-21 23:59:59.39
 1076834 | 1250113 | 2009-08-08 23:59:59.27
 1197074 | 1359962 | 2009-08-31 23:59:59.85
 1238060 | 1396654 | 2009-09-08 23:59:59.79
 1551372 | 1676327 | 2009-11-04 23:59:59.557
 1659243 | 1773927 | 2009-11-20 23:59:59.93
 1700045 |  274711 | 2009-11-27 23:59:59.687
 1737379 | 1843691 | 2009-12-03 23:59:59
 1816251 | 1911340 | 2009-12-15 23:59:59.593
 1853936 | 1943315 | 2009-12-21 23:59:59.953
 1886720 | 1895949 | 2009-12-28 23:59:59.09
 2010286 | 2077742 | 2010-01-16 23:59:59.403
```

One would expect<sup>*</sup> this kind of timestamp to appear with a probability of 1 in 86400 (there are 86400 seconds in a day). The data dump contains 1759400 comments, and:

```
1759400 / 86400 = 20.363426
```

There are 20 such comments in the above list.

> <sup>* disregarding the nonuniform distribution of activity on SO throughout the day</sup>

Comment: +1 for remembering to follow up =)

Answer (score 4):

Were you up all night making that graphic, hence able to post at 1 second before midnight??

Looks like the sql is doing a > 00:00:00 and < 23:59:59

Comment: Perhaps you mean `>= 00:00:00` and `<= 23:59:59`, where a timestamp with fractional seconds *after* 23:59:59 wouldn't be matched.

Comment: Looks like a good topic for a Coding Horror blog entry. "How *not* to filter on ranges"

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm specifying

`23:59:59.999`

instead of

`23:59:59`

in the SQL queries for this now

Comment: Why not specify `< endDate` and use the following day at 0:00 as input, instead of `<= endDate'?